# How to change default width of Radio button in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and radio button and radio button group, and i want to change radio button default width (It is taking 48px width ) I want to change it to 30px,

[image]

Please check screenshot.

Comment: Are you using a RadioGroup with FormControlLabels? Or just a simple Radio component? Or you could show us how are you trying to implement it

Answer (score 6):

Size of the radio button can changed by providing below code at root.

```
root: {
"& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      height: 15,
      width: 15,
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working to reduce radio button size.

Comment: This works, but instead of `weight: 15` use `width: 15` ... and maybe try '2.5em' instead of the unitless 15.

Answer (score 5):

The width is the result of 24px for the icon and then padding of 9px on each side (24 + 18 = 42) for the current version (v4.4.3) and padding of 12px on each side in v3 (24 + 24 = 48).

To get a width of 30px, you should adjust the padding to 3px (24 + 6 = 30).

You can control this in the theme by overriding the MuiRadio-root padding property:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiRadio: {
      root: {
        padding: 3
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And then wrap your component with ThemeProvider:

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      YOUR_COMPONENT
  </ThemeProvider>
```

[image: Edit Smaller Radio]

Comment: But this is actually not changing the width of the radio button, it's just changing the padding outside of it. And the questions asked was to change the width of radio button.